# Using references (temporary variables) to manipulate LinkedList?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

```
public void deleteItem(int target) 
{
    int index = 0;
    CarNode item = head;

    while(item != null)
    {

        CarNode next = (item.node).node;
        CarNode previous = item;

        if (index == target)
        {

            previous.setNode(next);

        }

    item = element.node
    index++;

    }
}
```

Yeah, I don't know if I understood well, but I got told that you can use reference and don't have to directly refer to an object of the linked list in order to perform changes on the linked list.

A node contains the Car object and the node of another element of the LinkedList, right, so the reference is basically a clone that points to the same object as the original, but how come that the original is ignored and the reference takes precedence over the original when we modify the node of the reference? Sorry, it didn't make any sense to me and I've been scratching my head for hours over this.

Comment: I suggest you review what a reference is and rephrase your question. It is very hard to figure out what you're having trouble with.  _"the reference takes precedence over the original when we modify the node of the reference"_ doesn't seem to make much sense, even in the context of your code.  Can you edit your post and rephrase the specific question?

Comment: by reference i mean next and previous as opposed to item.

Comment: Show us the definition of `CarNode`... and also, the line `CarNode next = (item.node).node;` seems to both contain an error (one of those `node`s should be a `next`) _and_ may also imply that the next pointer is in the data being stored in the list, and not in the listnode, which would be a design problem.

Comment: private class CarNode
  {
   private Car car;
   private CarNode node; }

Comment: do you want the entire class? because it only has your typical getters and setters.

Comment: What is it that you are asking here? Are you asking why this works? Or is there something about it that DOESN'T work?

Comment: I am wondering if it might work, if it's completely wrong, then I would like some explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should look like this:

```
public void deleteItem(int target) 
{
    int index = 0;
    CarNode item = head;
    CarNode prev = null;

    while(item != null)
    {
        if (index == target) {
            if (prev == null) {
                head = item.getNode();
                return; // We've removed the target.
            } else {
                prev.setNode(item.getNode());
                return; // We've removed the target.
            }
        }
        prev = item;
        item = item.getNode();
        index++;
    }
}
```

So let's break this down:

```
int index = 0;
CarNode item = head;
CarNode prev = null;
```

We need two variables: one to store the element we're looking at, the other to store the previous element (which we will use to reconnect the list once we remove an element). To start, our current is the head, and our previous doesn't exist. `index` will let us know when we reach the target.

```
while(item != null)
```

We want to iterate until we've hit the end of the list, marked by a `null` node.

```
if (index == target) {
    if (prev == null) {
        head = item.getNode();
        return; // We've removed the target.
    } else {
        prev.setNode(item.getNode());
        return; // We've removed the target.
    }
}
```

If we've found the target, we remove it. If previous is null, then the target was the head, so we move the head to the 2nd element. Otherwise, we make the previous node's reference to be the current node's reference, which cuts the current node out of the list. Once we remove the target, we are done, so we return.

```
prev = item;
item = item.getNode();
index++;
```

Update the previous and current nodes. Both are moved forward one node. Index is incremented.

How about an illustrated example:

Take a list of size 3. It looks like this:

[image: 1]

We now call `list.deleteItem(1);` This instantiates a `prev` and a `next` node. `next` points to the first node, and `prev` is null.

[image: 2]

Our target is 1, so we move to the next node. Now `prev` points to what `next` used to point to, and `next` points to the 2nd object in the list (the one we want to remove).

[image: 3]

We remove it by setting the `prev` node's reference to be the `next` node's reference.

[image: 4]

When we return from the method, java garbage collection does its job, and we're left with:

[image: 5]

Tada! Node removed from the list!

Comment: ahh i have difficulty parsing it, but what does return do exactly?

Comment: prev.node = item.node; and previous.setNode(next); are equivalent, right?

Comment: `return` ends the current method. And as for `previous.setNode(next)`, that would actually be the right call, if `node` is not public. I'll edit that. Hold on.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void deleteItem(int target) 
{
    int index = 0;
    CarNode item = head;

    CarNode next = null;
    CarNode previous = null;

    // stop when the linked-list ends
    while(item != null)
    {
        // the tail has no next node
        if (item.node != null)
            next = item.node.node;
        else
            next = null;

        // if targetIndex exist, remove it
        //     "logically" from the linekd-list
        if (index == target)
        {
            previous.setNode(next);
            break;
        }

        // today is tomorrow's yesterday
        previous = item;
        item = item.node;
        index++;

    }
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks, so there were a few errors, but no major logic errors. buw why did you break;?

Comment: check now @user2089523, I did `break` when we remove the target, since the target is associated with index\unique key, if it was associated with a value we can deal with multiple occurrences

Comment: @user2089523 Khaled's use of `break` is the same as my use of `return` (for this case, at least): it just serves to exit the method when we're done.

Comment: @user2089523 Jimmy's use of `return` is okay, personally I suggest avoid using `return` to break from a loop, `return` in the middle of a function is like abort, using `break` instead should enhance maintainability if in the future the function is modified ..

Comment: @user2089523 Alright. If you wanted to, you could substitute `break` in the places that I use `return`. It would do the same thing. Either way.